# While running npm start getting an error - '.' is not recognizable as an internal or external command

Tags: npm-start

I am running npm start command.
I am getting an error - '.' is not recognizable as an internal or external command. 
I am also attaching the npm start error log file.[NPM Start Error Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwHr6.png)

Please help

[NPM Start Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvAv6.png)